# How to display new created property value in Umbraco 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco5

I just want to know on how do I get the value of a property in umbraco 5.. 
in version 4.7 node.GetProperty("PropertyAlias").value

now. how do i use this in 5?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing a view, and you want to display a field from the current page's content, you can do so dynamically:

```
@CurrentPage.PropertyAlias
```

If you're editing a view, but the current page is not representative of the model, or you need more advanced features you can retrieve properties using the Field method:

```
@Umbraco.Field(Model, "PropertyAlias")
```

Finally, If you've selected a content node in code:

```
MyContent.Field<string>("PropertyAlias")
```